Movie about a son finding out his father is an alien
I vaguely remember an old movie (pre-2000) about a guy who finds out he's a human/alien hybrid.
I recall a scene where his mom is being mind-controlled or something, and waking up at night, and walking naked toward a spaceship.

Some of this fits The Day the World Ended

Note: This question is valid and can be answered.  I cannot remove the 'migrated' post notice, attempting to do so just errors.
